# Cost to train on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, resnet

I'm coming from academia where I had HPC clusters at my disposal.  Now I'm trying to deploy something on AWS.

I'm trying to budget for what it would cost, $-wise, to train some standard neural nets on standard data sets so I have an idea what other training will cost.  Even ballparkish estimates are appreciated.

I know you can request faster or more sets of GPUs, so I also don't know the spread of speed vs. cost either; any insight here is also appreciated.

What would it cost to train ResNet-50 (or really any smallish ResNet) on CIFAR-10, a relatively small net on a small data set? (say, 100 epochs with reasonable batch size)

Comment: This is a very broad question and it requires some pretty specific domain knowledge.  The [AWS Cost Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) can get you started but, again, you'll need to do some more research.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything on ResNet or CIFAR, but as far as pricing for AWS EC2 goes, it depends on instance family, type and reservations:

**On Demand Instances:** Higest cost. Ideal for prototyping and short lived environments. [Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)

**Reserved Instances:** Discount are based on the tenure of the reservation. You also have a No-Upfront option where you can reserve instances from 1 year to 3 years which does not provide maximum savings but significantly saves cost. [Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/pricing/)

**Spot Instances:** Cheapest option of all, but your application should be designed in way to handle interruptions as AWS will terminate your instance without notice. Recent announcement from AWS provides support for a termination notification for certain types of spot instances, which you may want to investigate. [Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/)